# Mysql return all results matching one column based on a value appearing at least once in another column

Tags: mysql

I'll try to explain what I need done...I have a table called 'quizzes' with data similar to this:

| quiz_id | username | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | john | 50 |
| 5 | mary | 75 |
| 9 | mary | 20 |
| 12 | tom | 15 |
| 12 | john | 13 |
| 12 | anne | 10 |
| 3 | john | 100 |
| 14 | john | 29 |

Note - there is only one person per quiz, it's like a record of 'high scores', so no person will have more than one row with a specific quiz_id.

What I want to do is pull all the results where John and at least one other person took that quiz, i.e. 'john' appears as a username and at one other person does too. So, the rows I would want returned are:

| quiz_id | username | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | john | 50 |
| 5 | mary | 75 |
| 12 | tom | 15 |
| 12 | john | 13 |
| 12 | anne | 10 |

As those are the only quizzes that john and at least one other person took, john didn't take 9, and only john took 3 and 14, so those aren't included either.

I've tried just SELECT quiz_id WHERE username = 'john' but obviously that only returns rows corresponding to his results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a join aggregation approach we can try:

```sql
SELECT t1.quiz_id, t1.username, t1.score
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT quiz_id
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY quiz_id
    HAVING SUM(username = 'john') > 0 AND   -- john is present
           SUM(username <> 'john') > 0      -- someone other than john is present
) t2
    ON t2.quiz_id = t1.quiz_id
ORDER BY
    t1.quiz_id;
```

Comment: yourTable is created from the following:

SELECT quiz_id,username,score FROM 
( SELECT initiator_user_id AS userid FROM wp_bp_friends WHERE friend_user_id = "1" AND is_confirmed = "1" 
UNION SELECT friend_user_id AS userid FROM wp_bp_friends WHERE initiator_user_id = "1" AND is_confirmed = "1" 
UNION SELECT '1' AS user_id) t1 
INNER JOIN wp_users t2 ON userid = t2.id 
INNER JOIN wp_huge_quiz_scores t3 ON t2.user_login = t3.username
INNER JOIN wp_posts t4 ON quiz_id=t4.id 
ORDER BY score DESC, time ASC

how can I add the INNER JOIN you mentioned to this query?

Comment: @DarinH Then place that query into a CTE and use my answer.